# Separate functions from the for loop in ghost

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ghost

Here is my code example below, there I used  **for loop** to get the data from ghost API and its working fine.  I want to append the data with dyanamic youtube image based on the post iframe's video code.

```
   single_carousel: function(){
          var post_type_two               = "carousel";
          var section_heading_one         = "Trending Videos";
          var single_carousel_container   = $(".video-carousel");
          var single_carousel_items       = "all";
          $(".section-heading-one h3").append(section_heading_one);
          $.get(ghost.url.api("posts",{        
            filter: "tag:"+post_type_two+"",
            limit : single_carousel_items
          })).done(function(data){
             var postsInfo = data.posts;
             if(postsInfo.length >0){
               for(var i=0;i < postsInfo.length; i++){
                      post_title   = postsInfo[i].title;
                      post_url     = postsInfo[i].url;
                      post_image   = postsInfo[i].image;
                      post_content = postsInfo[i].html;                  
                     $(".other").append("<div class='hidden'>"+post_content+"</div>");
                      if(post_image.length >0) {
                          single_carousel_container.append('<div class="single-video"><div class="video-img"><a href="'+post_url+'"><img src="'+post_image+'" alt="'+post_url+'" /></a><span class="video-duration">5.28</span></div><div class="video-content"><h4><a href="'+post_url+'" class="video-title">'+post_title+'</a></h4><div class="video-counter"><div class="video-viewers"> <span class="fa fa-eye view-icon"></span> <span>241,021</span></div><div class="video-feedback"><div class="video-like-counter"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-icon"></span> <span>2140</span></div><div class="video-like-counter"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down dislike-icon"></span> <span>2140</span></div></div></div></div></div>');
                      }
                $(".other .hidden").each(function(){
                var iframe_src =   $(this).find("iframe").attr("src");
                if(typeof iframe_src !== "undefined"){
                var video_id = iframe_src.slice(-11);
                var another_image =  'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/'+video_id+'/maxresdefault.jpg';                       
                if(another_image !== null && another_image !== "undefined" && another_image !== "" ) {
                console.log(another_image);
                         }
                 }
                 });
                }
                }
          });


     },
```

But I want to find the iframe by using **.other .hidden** class and successfully got the YouTube video ID there.

As example i  used the following function for that,

```
       $(".other .hidden").each(function(){
        var iframe_src =   $(this).find("iframe").attr("src");
        if(typeof iframe_src !== "undefined"){
        var video_id = iframe_src.slice(-11);
        var another_image =  'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/'+video_id+'/maxresdefault.jpg';                       
        if(another_image !== null && another_image !== "undefined" && another_image !== "" ) {
        console.log(another_image);
                 }
         }
         });
```

That is working fine also, Now i want to show specific image for each post items. Where actually showing multiple images right now.

Comment: Hint: you dont need the if around the for loop. If the array is empty, the loop will exit immeadiately, behaving like the if